# Why is "tengo" and not "tegno"?

Tags: verbs

Can anyone explain the reason why the verb "tenere" take the form "tengo", as in "io tengo", rather than the form "tegno", which sound more natural?

Comment: "Tegno" _is_ used in some dialects. See e.g. http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetto_veneto_occidentale

Comment: analogously, in the Sicilian dialect http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%A8niri, singular 1st person is "tegnu"

Comment: also, in the pugliese dialect "tegn" http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetti_della_Puglia

Answer (score 12):

Why does "tegno" sound more natural and why do you think that should be the form? Let's see the etymology. The verb comes, obviously, from Latin, and more precisely from **tĕnēre**. The first two from the verb conjugation are **tĕnĕo, tĕnes**.

It's easier for it to become *tengo* than *tegno*, which even loses the root *ten-* and therefore fails to deliver the proper meaning.

The root is the part that delivers the meaning of a word, so it's quite important. As far as Linguistics is concerned, it's hard to always explain the *why*, since unless you have more data, the reasons can be many and they can change for each case.